# Как сделать добавление селектов по кнопке?

Tags: ajax, javascript

Вот тут то, что уже работает: 
http://jsfiddle.net/394h7q82/4/
Нужно сделать добавление этих же двух селектов с другими name, чтобы функционал MkHousefromValues остался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/394h7q82/5/), не претендую на идеальность, хотел отобразить суть моих мыслей для реализации такого метода, а раз вы всё равно грузите jQuery, почему бы не использовать библиотеку по-полной.

Comment: Спасибо. 
А как им теперь при добавлении у селектов менялся name. 
town_select_1
town_select_2
town_select_3
и т.д ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/394h7q82/7/ вот так можно, name у обоих динамические, а в jquery как селекторы можно использовать и классы элементов.